# What is the difference between enumerate and range(len(list)) in python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, range

Can someone tell me why the two code below give me different results? I was under the impression that the enumerate and range(len(list)) both are iterable.

Code: Trying to find the equilibrium index of an array

```
def equisum (arr):
    tsum = sum(arr)
    lsum = 0
    num = len(arr)
    for i in range(num):
        tsum -= num
        if lsum == tsum:
            return i
        lsum += num
    return -1
arr = [-7, 1, 5, 2, -4, 3, 0]
print (equisum (arr))  

Result : -1

def equisum (arr):
    tsum = sum(arr)
    lsum = 0
    for i, num in enumerate(arr):
        tsum -= num
        if lsum == tsum:
            return i
        lsum += num
    return -1
arr = [-7, 1, 5, 2, -4, 3, 0]
print (equisum (arr))  

Result : 3 (the correct answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

`range(num)` will give the values `0, 1, 2...`.

`enumerate(arr)` will give the values `(0, -7), (1, 1), (2, 5)...` where the first value is the index and the second value is value of `arr` at that index.

Your second function should give the correct answer because it subtracts the value of `arr[i]` rather than just `i`.

Answer (score 0):

`range()` is used for getting the sequence of numbers. For example if you give `range(10)`, it will give numbers from 0 to 9.

Here, as you are using `range`, you are calculating the numbers wrong and finally the default `-1` is being returned.

While in `enumerate()`, it returns both index and *actual* element from the list.

by the way, if you are using VS Code for programming, make use of the **debug** feature. It will help to identify such issues much faster.